# what is the best way to check Internet connection continuously in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am developing an application. In that one screen check Internet connection, immediately after onCreate() method. If network connection is good i am calling one AsyncTask class for load countries list and show it on screen in spinnerView. If there is no network connection i am showing Toast Message to User and call check_Network(AsyncTask). In this class protected Long doInBackground(URL... params) method i'm checking Network connected or not if connected call countries AsyncTask otherwise again i am calling check_Network(AsyncTask). this process repeat until network is connected. my problem is It is correct way for Check Network Repeatedly. please suggested me. sorry i am poor in english please understand.blow i am showing my code

```
if (CheckNetwork.isOnline(this)) {
            try {
                new CountryProcess().execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {


            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.network_connection_fail)
                            + "!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            new NetWork_connectivity().execute();
}

//.......................//

class NetWork_connectivity extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer,Long>
    {
        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(URL... params)
        {
            if (CheckNetwork.isOnline(MainActivity.this)) {

                new CountryProcess().execute();

            }else
            {
                new NetWork_connectivity().execute();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just let the country list RPC go through, and then report the toast if it fails?

Comment: i stay that screen for long time, so again how can i call CountryProcess Async Class

Answer (score 8):

Add below code in manifest, for adding receiver with connectivity change intent

```
<receiver android:name=".NetworkStateReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And at receiver side, get extras associated with intent and check for status. So whenever there is change in network status, you will be notified then perform your task accordingly.

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 super.onReceive(context, intent);
 if(intent.getExtras()!=null) {
    NetworkInfo ni=(NetworkInfo) intent.getExtras().get(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
    if(ni!=null && ni.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        //connected
    }
 }
 if(intent.getExtras().getBoolean(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY,Boolean.FALSE)) {
        //not connected
 }
}
}
```

For your case, you would like to add permission in manifest and register receiver in your activity.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(networkReceiver, filter);
```

Make sure to unregister it as well before leaving activity with

```
unregisterReceiver(networkReceiver);

private BroadcastReceiver networkReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     super.onReceive(context, intent);
     if(intent.getExtras()!=null) {
        NetworkInfo ni=(NetworkInfo) intent.getExtras().get(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if(ni!=null && ni.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            //connected
        }
     }
     //not connected 
   }
}
```

And based upon your requirement that you requires connected status only one time. First check for connectivity and if not connected then only register receiver.

```
public boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Anupam it is best way.

Answer (score 1):

> To access internet we need INTERNET Permission
>   To detect network status we need ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE Permission

Add these lines in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<!-- Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Network State Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Create this method in your java class:

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null) 
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null) 
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
```

When ever you want to check Internet Status in your application call `isConnectingToInternet()` function and it will return true or false

```
ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet(); // true or false
```