# Android - Check Active Internet connection without make network call

Tags: android

Is there a way to check Internet connection without make a network call? Libraries links are appreciated!

All the example I saw is kind of that:

```
 fun hasInternetConnection(): Single<Boolean> {
 return Single.fromCallable {
  try {
  // Connect to Google DNS to check for connection
  val timeoutMs = 1500
  val socket = Socket()
  val socketAddress = InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53)

  socket.connect(socketAddress, timeoutMs)
  socket.close()

       true
     } catch (e: IOException) {
       false
  }
}
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354449/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-internet-connection-continuously-in-android/31354570#31354570

Answer (score 1):

[Reactive Network](https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveNetwork) is the library for you since you already use RxJava. The code will look like this:

```
ReactiveNetwork.observeNetworkConnectivity(context)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            // anything else what you can do with RxJava
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<Connectivity>() {
                @Override public void accept(final Connectivity connectivity) {
                    // do something with connectivity
                    // you can call connectivity.getState();
                    // connectivity.getType(); or connectivity.toString();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: call the method in onCreate

```
private boolean chechInternetConnection() {

    connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            connected = true;
            Log.i("Internet", "Connected");
        } else {
            connected = false;
            Log.i("Internet", "Not Connected");
        }
    }
    return connected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. I'm already using this in my projects.

```
fun getConnectivityStatus(context: Context): Boolean {
    try {
        val cm = context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val activeNetwork = cm.activeNetworkInfo
        if (activeNetwork != null) {
            if (activeNetwork.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                return true

            if (activeNetwork.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                return true
        }
    } catch (aThrowable: Throwable) {
        return false
    }

    return false
}
```